# UnloadUnusedAssets doesn't appear to be freeing memory

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game in Unity where a sprite is imported using Resources.Load(), and as expected, the memory increases.
But the problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to free the memory.

I know I need to use Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets(), but even when I remove every reference to the sprite that I can think of, the memory doesn't go back down.

Here's my code right now:

Loading the sprite (works fine):

```
map = Resources.Load <Sprite> ("Map7");
spRend = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
spRend.sprite = map;
```

Unloading the sprite (memory isn't freed):

```
spRend.sprite = null;
map = null;
Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
```

UPDATE:

After further research, I found this on the Unity wiki:

> When not used anymore, you can free the memory it took up by calling Object.Destroy on the object, followed by Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets

But the problem is when I try to destroy 'map', I get the following error:

```
Destroying assets is not permitted to avoid data loss.
If you really want to remove an asset use DestroyImmediate (theObject, true);
```

Comment: Is the memory getting freed when the GC is called? Also according to the [unity3d reference page](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets.html) you need to call `EditorUtility.SetDirty`

Comment: No, the memory never goes back down, even when I manually call the GC. Also, from what I read, 'EditorUtility.SetDirty' is only for use within the editor; I get an error if I try to build.

Comment: How about using `EditorUtility.UnloadUnusedAssetsImmediate` ?

Comment: I meant all of 'EditorUtility' is only for editor use.

Comment: What happens when you do what the error message suggests?

Comment: It corrupted the image file, and I had to re-import it.

Going back, I think I've figured out what the problem was:
When I was originally trying this, I was using Unity 4 Free version, which doesn't include the Profiler, so I was using looking at the memory usage in the Windows Task Manager while running the .exe, and I just found out that the newly released Unity 5 Free version comes with  the Profiler, so I tried that out instead.
The memory usage was similar, but in Profiler, it actually DID go back down when the sprite was unloaded.
So now I'm just curious why only the Profiler showed it.